# Angular swPush notificationonclick works in development mode but not in production

Tags: angular, web, push-notification

I'm developing an angular website with push notification and I'm using swPush to do it. The problem is I can't make it open an URL in prod mod. In dev mode works just fine.

I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/) and got the ngsw-worker [file](https://github.com/u-ryo/angular-swpush/blob/master/docs/ngsw-worker.js) from a project in github

I normally don't program in angular so I don't know what exactly I need to put here to help so please tell me what else you guys need to know and I'll add.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you serve your application over https in production mode?

> The next generation of push, implemented by both Google and Mozilla will be done through ServiceWorkers.
>
> Push API spec
> In that case yes, your content will need to be served over HTTPS.

Comment: yes, the site is in https but the weird thing is that it works in localhost (http)

Comment: works in localhost because you as developer can test your solution before upload to the production server. You can compare localhost to sandbox.